# Change Button color

Tags: excel, vba, commandbutton

I'm using excel and I'm having trouble, I need buttons that will change color when clicked. I can use a command button but it needs me to label each of them individual "CommandButton1, CommandButton2 ,CommandButton3 ...CommandButton1000." I will be using many of them and wanted to know what I should be doing so I could have one general macros program a can slap on a shape/command button. This program only needs to change the color  back and forth when clicked. [This is what I'm working with.](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/change-command-button-to-a-different-color-by-clicking-on-button-vba-excel.864406/)

```
'Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

Select Case CommandButton1.BackColor

    Case -2147483633 'Default Grey
    col = 228 'FP Red
    Case Else
    col = -2147483633 'Default Grey
End Select
 
CommandButton1.BackColor = col
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this can be done manually but I would like to do it with something simpler than this^

Comment: Where are these button located?  You can either stick with activeX and use a "control array" (Google for that term) or switch to shapes, link them all to the same macro, then use `Application.Caller` in the macro to id the shape which initiated the call.

Comment: Just to add: Using colors all by themselves to indicate something is considered bad design. Colors make a good secondary indicator used to draw attention to something, but if things in a GUI are changing colors and it isn't obvious to the user as to why they are changing color, that will just create confusion.

Comment: Another option (probably a lazy one) is to write a code generator. Copy the output and paste it in the right sheet/form module. If you have permission to change the vbe programatically, you can even change the code in the module directly.

Comment: I wrote this way back in 2011. Hope this helps in creating [control array](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend inserting a module into the workbook and write generic color changing code there.  Then in the sheet with the buttons, simply call that code and pass the sub the button clicked.  The module sub would look something like this:

```
Public Sub ColorChange(ByRef btn As Object)
    Select Case btn.Name
    Case "CommandButton1"
        btn.BackColor = RGB(200, 0, 0)
    Case "CommandButton2"
        btn.BackColor = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    Case "CommandButton3"
        btn.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 200)
    Case "CommandButton4"
        btn.BackColor = RGB(200, 0, 200)
    End Select
End Sub 'ColorChange
```

The button click would look something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call ColorChange(Me.CommandButton1)
End Sub
```

You can put whatever changes you like depending on which button is clicked.  Also, you can name the buttons whatever you want.  Right click the button and go to properties and you can change the name.  Typical naming convention for a button is to prefix the control with cmd or btn and a name. For example, btnColor1.  But that's all up to you, of course.

P.S. Control arrays for large numbers of controls is probably a good idea.  Check this out:
https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/vba-control-arrays.htm